# Is this a bug in a xml parser?

Tags: xml, xml-rpc

I wonder if there is bug in a xml parser because of the following problem.

I use a XMLRPC package which uses an xml parser.
I debugged the package. I can see this.
The server returns an xml which something like this:

```
<value><string>line1\nline2\nline3\n</string></value>
```

\n represesnts literal new line character (10,13 or 10).

The parser returns a string which is "line1\nline2\nline3" without the final \n.
My question is .. Is this bug if the xml parser does not return the final \n?

Answer:
Yes, it is a bug.

Comment: In your text, does `\n` represent the newline character or a literal backslash and `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be a bug caused by badly used xml parser....

Pointy showed the way.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you get back "trimmed" strings from XML APIs. I don't know what parser you're using, but it might be possible to tell it you want an "untrimmed" value.